# js.executeScript doesn't work when using getElementsByClassName in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have a method:

```
public void delayToCapture(String methodGetBy, String key){
    /* List of methodGetBy:
     * 1. getElementById
     * 2. getElementsByTagName
     * 3. getElementsByClassName
     * 4. querySelectorAll
     */

    System.out.println("Excuteing javaScript...");              

    if(methodGetBy.equals("getElementById")){
        js.executeScript("setTimeout(function(){ document." +methodGetBy+ "('" +key+ "').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');},500);");
    }
    else if(methodGetBy.equals("getElementsByClassName")){
        js.executeScript("setTimeout(function(){"
                        + "var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('"+ key +"');"
                        + "for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){"
                        + "elems[i].style.display = 'none';}"
                        + "},"
                        + "500);");
    }

}
```

And I call that method in another class:

```
delayToCapture("getElementsByClassName", "positionmenu");
```

When running the code, console always show me this message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

However, if I run this code at below on console of Brower directly -> It's work:

```
setTimeout(function(){
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('positionmenu');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
elems[i].style.display = 'none';
}
},500);
```

So, could you tell me what is the reason here?

Comment: Whether it is working for the getElementById block? whether js is an object of the JavascriptExecutor ?

Comment: Yes, with getElementById -> It's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this :

```
 else if(methodGetBy.equals("getElementsByClassName")){
        List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.className(key));  // getting element using class name
        js.executeScript("setTimeout(function(){"
                        + "var elems = arguments[0];"
                        + "for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){"
                        + "elems[i].style.display = 'none';}"
                        + "},"
                        + "500);", element);
    }
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: + "var elems = arguments[0];"

Could you tell me what is arguments? And why using it?

//It doesn't work

Comment: It is the variable or you can say the list of all elements containing this class. Sorry if it did not worked for you.

Comment: Please try now. You can also put "console.log(elems.length)" in your javascript code to see in console if the length is correct for all elements containing class "positionmenu". It should work. I have edited the above code for getting list of WebElements instead of single element

Comment: If you are getting any exception than please show me the stacktrace

Comment: I run console.log(elems.length) in console of Brower, then return = "undefined"

Comment: Show me what you are getting in console when you execute code : var menus = document.getElementsByClassName("positionmenu");
console.log("menu length is :" + menus.length);
for (i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) { 
    console.log(menus[i]);
}  in console

Comment: and also try to run it using selenium in JavascripExecutor remaining all things same. It will show that code is working or not and where exactly is the problem

Comment: var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('positionmenu'); console.log('length= '+elems.length); for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){elems[i].style.display = 'none';}

Comment: I don't know why it returns = 1 now

Comment: How many elements actually you have for class name "positionmenu" on GUI. I do not know where is the problem but if you want to discuss than ping me at sandpdangi13@gmail.com. I would be happy to help you out if I can.